# Issue with volume calculation

Tags: meshlab

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VwNp.png)

Please find the attached file, Why I can't calculate the volume for any object?
This message does appear when I use the Mac or Windows.

Regards,
  Ali

Comment: Do you mean to say you can calculate the volume in Linux but not in Windows/Mac?

Answer (score 0):

This error will be generated only if the mesh is not watertight, i.e. either the mesh has some boundary edges (holes) or some non-manifold edges.

Try with some different models to confirm. For example, generate a sphere in MeshLab (`Filters -> Create New Mesh layer -> Sphere`) and calculate volume.

PS: You can remove non-manifold edges in MeshLab and close the holes to make the model watertight.

Answer (score 0):

"One thing to keep in mind is that duplicate faces within a mesh will affect the calculation of volume and moment of inertia."

If you have this situation, it can also contribute to the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).